# Time to arrive with dynamic speeds per hour

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am writing an algorithm and I have come up against what I think should be a simple problem, but the solution is eluding me.  I'll phrase it in the style of "a train traveling at $x \ \textrm{mph}$" (please forgive me):

#### The problem

A plane flies at a base rate of $R_b$ over a distance $d$. In a simple world, the amount of time it would take would simply be $\frac{d}{R_b}$. However, I need to account for wind. Wind predictions are available every hour, and for simplicity's sake, we will say that the wind predicted at a certain hour is constant for that entire hour.

The magnitude of the wind ($w$) in the direction of flight has a non-linear affect on $R_b$. For now, let's just say that the rate of flight in hour $i$ ($R_i$), as tempered by the wind, can be given as a function of $R_b$ and $w_i$ (where $w_i$ is the wind for hour $i$ from the weather prediction):

$$R_i = f(R_b, w_i)$$

I need to determine the formula that will tell me when the plane will arrive at its destination.

#### Thinking through the first few iterations

If we can safely assume that the distance can be traveled in under an hour, it would simply be

$$\frac{d}{R_1}$$

However, if we know that $d$ will certainly take between $1$ and $2$ hours to travel, it would be something like

$$\frac{d - (R_1 \times 1 \ \textrm h)}{R_2} + 1 \ \textrm h$$

Going one step further, assuming it takes between $2$ and $3$ hours

$$\frac{d - (R_1 \times 1 \ \textrm h) - (R_2 \times 1 \ \textrm h)}{R_3} + 2 \ \textrm h$$

And so forth.  (I *think* that's right?).

#### Creating a generic formula

How can I write a formula for when I have *no idea* how long its going to take? Meaning I know all $w_i$ and can dynamically calculate all $R_i$ at the time the function runs, but not before?

Comment: Do you know calculus? The integral of speed is distance which is the formula you want.

Comment: I do know calculus, but its admittedly been many years since I was doing it daily.  @HaydnHwyn's answer sums up your point exactly in his last ingegral formula.  But 2 things - (1) I'm trying to solve for *time*, not distance, so I'd need to invert the integral, which (2) I'm not sure how to do for a peicewise function like I have.  However, his answer really helped, as it is in algorithm form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the plane's distance travelled as a function of time. This is a piecewise linear function such that
$$d(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n R_i$$
where $n$ is an integer. The inverse of a piecewise linear function is again piecewise linear function, which means if we write it down, it ends up looking something like
$$\mathrm{time}(d) = \begin{cases} \text{expression 1} & \text{plane takes between 0 and 1 hours} \\ \text{expression 2} & \text{plane takes between 1 and 2 hours} \\ \vdots \end{cases}$$
In other words, there's not a super nice way to write this down mathematically that avoids doing the casework you mentioned. That being said, if you had a smoother approximation for intra-hour wind speeds, you might be able to get something nicer.

As far as an algorithm goes, however, this can still be done nicely. I think your algorithm could look something like this (python):

```
def flight_time(d, Rb, list_of_wind_speeds):
  # i represents the number of hours that have passed
  i = 0
  # keep passing time until the plane has reached its destination
  while d > 0:
    i += 1
    wi = list_of_wind_speeds[i]
    Ri = get_wind_speed(Rb, wi)
    # when the ith hour passes, the plane travels another Ri in distance
    d -= Ri
  return d/Ri + i
```

In the very last step, the variable `d` contains the quantity $d-R_1 - R_2 - \cdots - R_i$, where the plane reaches its destination in the $i$th hour. This means that the actual time taken is
$$\frac{d-R_1-R_2-\cdots-R_{i-1}}{R_i} + i-1 = \frac{d - R_1 - R_2 - \cdots - R_i}{R_i} + i$$
and hence we can get our final answer by returning `d/Ri + i`.

The following may or may not be helpful: to elaborate a bit more on what I mean by "a smoother approximation for intra-hour wind speeds", imagine if we modeled wind speed as a function of time as follows:
$$w(t) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i e^{-(t-i)^2}$$
Then we can compute the function $R(t) = f(R_b, w_i)$, and, as suggested by Eric, the distance travelled by the plane after time $t$ is
$$d(t) = \int_0^t R(t) \, dt$$
Depending on the function $f$, the inverse of this function may be easily computable.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, especially the algorithm part.  The calculus makes sense, but I'm not sure that finding the inverse of ()=∫() would be simple, especially considering I really do have discretized wind speeds by the hour.  One thing I'm confused about....in your algorithm you write `d -= Ri` - is there an implied `d -= Ri * 1` here, because we're incrementing over 1 hour, and assuming `Ri` is in d/hr units?  The units of time in my actual code are not as clear and consistent as to always use units of 1 hour, so I need to consider that as well.

Comment: Yes, there is an implied `d -= Ri * 1` which could, for example, be replaced by `d -= Ri * unit_conversion_factor`.